# Async Json.net deserialization

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, json.net

As it [is mentioned here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html) (great blog, btw), for correct work of CPU-bound calls, proper async calls are needed. For example, not

```
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
```

but

```
    await Task.Delay(100);
```

---

Is there analogue for Json.net deserializing ?

```
    await TaskEx.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PocoProduct>(resultString));
```

The context of usage:

```
async public Task<ProductsAnswer> RequestServerAsync()
{
    // Just a wrapper for await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync() and await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()
    var resultString = await new NetworkManager().GetAsync(Constants.SERVER_REQUEST); 

    // await TaskEx.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PocoProduct>(resultString));
    var answer = await ParseProductsFromString(resultString); 

    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of that blog post is to avoid blocking calls for operations that aren't CPU bound, such as delaying, or disk/network IO.

Parsing JSON is an inherently CPU-bound operation; the best you can do is move that work to a different thread.

Comment: But isn't TaskEx.Run() schedule and run Func in the background thread?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko: Yes.  That's the best you can do.

Comment: Interestingly, Json.NET does exactly what Stephen Cleary thinks should not be done.  It wraps its synchronous CPU bound methods into async methods by wrapping them with `Task.Factory.StartNew` such as for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync`.

Comment: @TrevorElliott: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Comment: @SLaks It's not clear as to whether you're implying "see here for why Json.NET is justifyably written that way" or "see here for why it shouldn't be."  But I definitely don't think it should be since it's not adhering to a base class/interface or acting itself as a base class.

Comment: Thanks for article, now i got what mean by *avoid blocking calls for operations that aren't CPU bound*: that timer would just waste one of the threads for waiting.

Comment: @TrevorElliott: The latter.

Comment: @SLaks link from Nov 11, 2013 comment is broken. Check it out in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160605223655/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx?PageIndex=3